# How can I correctly input vendor JS file in to Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have been working on a face recognition web app, which I use face-api.min.js from this official website https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html

The js file is in min.js type, where I can just refer in  in normal html and js file. However, when I put in Rails 6, it shows faceapi is not defined, where I pretty sure it doesn't able to load it. I put the min.js file in my assets/javascript/packs and writing a java script file to perform the logic. It works fine with normal html, js file but when in rails it just doesnt work

BTW this is the js file https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/blob/master/dist/face-api.min.js

Does any one know how can I import this?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues adding select2 and requiring the js properly in Rails 6 app. It was a preconfigured app from work and config is not my strong suit as I didn't want to change something that would affect the greater application. [This blob post](https://rubyyagi.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-and-jquery-in-rails-6-with-webpacker#using-custom-javascript-library-which-is-not-available-on-npm) that helped a ton.

Basically it has you download the select2 files and add them to the packs in a custom folder, then require that folder in your packs/aplication.js

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try it and update again